# ASP.NET API optional parameters not recognized?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-apicontroller

First of all, thanks for reading this.
I've been racking my brains the whole morning as to why I'm getting a 400 Bad Request along with this error:

> {
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
> "status": 400,
> "traceId": "00-1d24680c387efe1052e1dbc828a40b62-5b8bed004edfa9a9-00",
> "errors": {
> "notes": [
> "The notes field is required."
> ]
> }
> }

I've removed all code, except for the return statement, all other parameters, yet still no luck.

My code is as follows:

```
[HttpPost("foo")]
        public IEnumerable<bar> foo(string notes = "")
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 1).Select(index => new bar
            {
                output = "Updated"
            });
        }
```

The request I'm sending is

> https://localhost:7043/Update/?notes=

If my code is correct, this shouldn't be a problem since notes is optional, right?

Any help is appriciated, thank you :)

Comment: Using `<Name Removed:>` is **not helpful** because it's not a syntactically valid C# identifier. Please just use normal [metasyntactic names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) like `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` instead of doing your own thing.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is likely because you have `[HttpPost]` applied, so ASP.NET defaults to assuming `string notes` will be read from the request-body (I think?). To force `notes` to be interpreted as an optional querystring parameter you need to apply `[FromQuery]` to the parameter: `public IEnumerable<Whatever> MyActionMethod( [FromQuery] String notes = "" )`. (That said, you should not be passing data-to-persist in querystring params: you should be using a strongly-typed request-body DTO).

Comment: @Dai thanks for your feedback, i’ve updated the names. As for [FromQuery] , i’ve tried and it’s still not working.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? Do you have `[ApiController]` applied? Any custom middleware?

Comment: Yes and yes, weirdest thing though, i’ve got another function higher up the page with optional params and it’s working…